# How do I clear a thinpool device for docker

Tags: docker, redhat, device-mapper

I am running docker on a Redhat system with devicemapper and thinpool device just as recommended for production systems. Now when I want to reinstall docker I need two steps:

1) remove docker directory (in my case /area51/docker)
2) clear thinpool device

The [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#options-per-storage-driver) states that when using devicemapper with dm.metadev and dm.datadev options, the easiest way of cleaning devicemapper would be:

> If setting up a new metadata pool it is required to be valid. 
>   This can be achieved by zeroing the first 4k to indicate empty metadata, like this:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=$metadata_dev bs=4096 count=1
```

Unfortunately, according to the documentation, the `dm.metadatadev` is deprecated, it says to use `dm.thinpooldev` instead.

My thinpool has been created along the lines of [this docker instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/#configure-direct-lvm-mode-for-production)
So, my setup now looks like this:

```
cat /etc/docker/daemon.json  
{
        "storage-driver": "devicemapper", 
        "storage-opts": [ 
        "dm.thinpooldev=/dev/mapper/thinpool_VG_38401-thinpool",
        "dm.basesize=18G"
        ]  
}
```

Under the devicemapper directory i see the following thinpool devices

```
ls -l /dev/mapper/thinpool_VG_38401-thinpool*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Dec  6 08:31 /dev/mapper/thinpool_VG_38401-thinpool -> ../dm-8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Dec  6 08:31 /dev/mapper/thinpool_VG_38401-thinpool_tdata -> ../dm-7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Dec  6 08:31 /dev/mapper/thinpool_VG_38401-thinpool_tmeta -> ../dm-6
```

So, after running docker successfully I tried to reinstall as described above and clear the thinpool by writing 4K zeroes into the tmeta device and restart docker:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/thinpool_VG_38401-thinpool_tmeta bs=4096 count=1  
systemctl start docker
```

And endet up with

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-12-06 10:28:46 UTC; 10s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 1566 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -G uwsgi --data-root=/area51/docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1566 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Memory: 236.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service

Dec 06 10:28:45 yoda3 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Dec 06 10:28:45 yoda3 dockerd[1566]: time="2017-12-06T10:28:45.816049000Z" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 1577"
Dec 06 10:28:46 yoda3 dockerd[1566]: time="2017-12-06T10:28:46.816966000Z" level=warning msg="failed to rename /area51/docker/tmp for background deletion: renam...chronously"
Dec 06 10:28:46 yoda3 dockerd[1566]: Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: devmapper: Unable to take ownership of thin-pool (thinpool_VG_38401-...data blocks
Dec 06 10:28:46 yoda3 systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 06 10:28:46 yoda3 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 06 10:28:46 yoda3 systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Dec 06 10:28:46 yoda3 systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

I assumed I could get around the 'unable to take ownership of thin-pool' by doing a reboot. But after reboot and trying to start docker again I got the following error:

```
systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-12-06 10:30:37 UTC; 2min 29s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 3180 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -G uwsgi --data-root=/area51/docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3180 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Memory: 37.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service

Dec 06 10:30:36 yoda3 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Dec 06 10:30:36 yoda3 dockerd[3180]: time="2017-12-06T10:30:36.893777000Z" level=warning msg="libcontainerd: makeUpgradeProof could not open /var/run/docker/lib...containerd"
Dec 06 10:30:36 yoda3 dockerd[3180]: time="2017-12-06T10:30:36.901958000Z" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 3224"
Dec 06 10:30:37 yoda3 dockerd[3180]: Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: devicemapper: Non existing device thinpool_VG_38401-thinpool 
Dec 06 10:30:37 yoda3 systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 06 10:30:37 yoda3 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 06 10:30:37 yoda3 systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Dec 06 10:30:37 yoda3 systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

So, obviously writing zeroes into the thinpool_meta device is not the right thing to do, it seems to destroy my thinpool device.

Anyone here that can tell me the right steps to clear the thin-pool device? Preferably the solution should not require a reboot.